# Printf function show struct differently

Tags: go, printf

I am using compile function of regex package which returns pointer of *Regexp* struct and passing struct in printf function shows me only string not whole struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    reg, _ := regexp.Compile(`[0-9a-f]+`)
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", reg)
}

// Output
[0-9a-f]+
```

But when I created my own struct and initialising with some value and print it then it shows full struct. I am not understanding the concept here.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Exp struct {
    a           string 
    b           int
}

func main() {
    x := &Exp{"akash", 12}
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", x)
}

// Output: &{akash 12}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`regexp.Regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp) type implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface, which is the default verb used in the `fmt.Print*` methods.

This means that it calls `reg.String()` when formatting in your first example.

In your second example, your custom type `Exp`, has no such method, so it uses default Go-formatting of the struct.